# Why does BTRFS filesystem mount automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, fstab, btrfs, automounting

So I've made a btrfs filesystem that spans across one logical drive (md1) and a USB drive. its all raid 0. so that:

```
sata\
      md1--\
sata/        \  
               btrfs called "Storage"
usb---------/
```

I've put a line in fstab using UUID=

```
UUID=2cf6d402-7279-4bdd-b0f8-6931c5db9fe1 /media/<user>/Storage auto x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

When I mount it via command line ie sudo mount -a everything mounts normally and the only mount point is /media/user/Storage

However, if I reboot it mounts twice for some reason. I get one at /m/u/Storage and another at /m/u/Storage1.

I've noticed this has something to do with the label because before it used to mount at /m/u/btrfs and /mnt/Storage, only the latter of which was in my /etc/fstab.

has me scratching my head.
PS, ubuntu mini iso installation with mate-desktop-minimal, 18.04 lts. normal kernel fresh install all packages up to date. I'm making a nas

EDIT:
I've commented out the fstab and rebooted. The filesystem still mounts at /media/user/Storage. Is this normal BTRFS behavior in ubuntu? And can it be switched off? I wouldn't mind this if I could change its mountpoint; I don't want it in the user directory.

Comment: Are you logged in with some graphical desktop? Perhaps that's mounting the filesystem. Try booting into a text mode only environment and then logging in as root and checking the mounts then.

Comment: i am using a gui, mate. is there a way i can make mate not mount btrfs at boot?

Comment: I don't think that this second mount has anything to do with BTRFS. It's probably an auto-mounter (`udisks2`?) that mounts your USB drive.

Comment: ok so i need to figure out how to exclude a specific device from udisks2. i can manage that i think. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I just encountered similar behaviour which was not only annoying but also seemed to be causing disk i/o to slow to a crawl on my btrfs raid10 external drive. The interaction between btrfs and automount is not great; I would also see mounts accumulate up to `Storage10` the device never disconnected, but the system would keep remounting it (I have a hypothesis at the end of this answer).

Anyway, I solved this by disabling automount. This only applies to desktop environments, ubuntu server does not automount drives so this is not an issue on server where there is no `gnome` or `nautilus` running.

To disable automount in ubuntu 22.04 Desktop you can run:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/media-handling/automount false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/media-handling/automount-open false
```

The second line seems to be optional but the general recommendation from [other pages](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/20107) seems to be to disable both (and I generally agree it looks silly to see the automount-open feature enabled when automount is disabled).

This is an **all-or-nothing** setting so it also disables automount for normal usb drives and sd cards that are not `btrfs raid` and would not have this issue. Not a huge deal for me, it's a single click in nautilus to mount any visible drive. But if someone knows a better or more targeted solution I would be curious to learn.

I believe this has something to do with how btrfs handles raid. With btrfs when you raid 2 devices you can mount either one to your host and btrfs will automagically handle the raid across all devices under the covers. I think this confuses the automount logic which sees an unused device and keeps trying to mount it. That is just a guess though. Either way, disabling auto mount for btrfs raid saved me a major headache.